# Store Drawings of PKCanvasView in file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, document-based, pencilkit

I created a document based app with SwiftUI and a PKCanvasView.
Now I want to save the drawings of the PKCanvasView inside of the file.
How can I do this?

Comment: `PKCanvasView` has a `drawing` property, which in turn has a `dataRepresentation()` method that gives you data you can save to a file.

Comment: @jnpdx How can I do this? Do you know a good tutorial? Or can you tell it me?

Comment: I can, but it would be helpful to see your attempt and where you got stuck -- then I'll know what the structure of your code looks like.

Comment: @jnpdx I asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883267/turn-data-of-pkcanvasview-in-datarepresentation-and-save-it-to-custom-file) with some code and I  hope you can answer it.